# Recovering files from an old TrueCrypt file that uses a Linux FS

Tags: windows, filesystems, truecrypt

I have an old file created with TrueCrypt, which I need to recover the files from. I know the decryption key, that's not the problem. I can use VeraCrypt to open it. The problem is that the file uses (AFAIK) a Linux file system (possibly ext2 or ext3), and I currently only have a Windows computer, so even if I use VeraCrypt (or even TrueCrypt) to mount it, Windows is incapable of reading it. I don't think the file is corrupted or anything; it's just that Windows doesn't support the FS in it.

I tried to use the DiskInternals LinuxReader utility to try to read it, but it just doesn't list the drive mounted by VeraCrypt at all (and I can't figure out any way of telling it to handle it like it were a normal disk drive).

What would be the easiest way to do this? Is there, perhaps, some kind of live linux CD that contains VeraCrypt, which could be used to copy the files somewhere else?

Comment: I wonder if a veracrypt rescue boot disk can read the file system.

Comment: You could try a Linux live session but I'm not sure installing Veracrypt in a live session is easy or not.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this a long time ago, but never returned to this question, so I'll answer it now: The solution was actually surprisingly simple: Just install a linux distro in a virtual machine (VMware in my case), and do the recovery there. Really easy and simple.